# Actualizar campo tabla a partir de otra

Tags: sql-server

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

USER

```
usuario: id number, name varchar2
              1        PEPE
              2        LUCAS
```

REPORT

```
reporte: id number, usuario_id, owner varchar2
            1          1            NULL
            2          2            NULL
```

En la tabla reporte, tengo registros que hacen referencia la tabla usuario, 
¿Es posible hacer un update para que en el campo ownwer me ponga el nombre del agente?

Comment: Si.. que intentaste???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías utilizar un subquery, algo así:

```
UPDATE report
SET owner = (SELECT name FROM user WHERE user.id = report.usuario_id)
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: gracias me sirvio tanto en sqlserver como en oracle

Answer (score 3):

Una manera distinta de hacer el `update`, que solo es soportada por *SQL Server*, pero que viene muy bien para actualizaciones complejas, es la sentencia `update/from`. Tiene la ventaja que puede tener múltiples joins, con la condición que cada fila de la tabla a actualizar quede solo 1 vez en el resultado de los `join`s.

En tu caso, que no es tan complejo, la sentencia quedaría algo como:

```
update report
   set owner = user.name
  from report
       inner join user on user.id = report.usuario_id
```

Puedes utilizar alias, en ambas tablas, con lo que podría quedar como:

```
update r
   set owner = u.name
  from report r
       inner join user u on u.id = r.usuario_id
```

Como dije antes, la principal ventaja de este tipo de actualización es que puedes tener múltiples `join`s.

Comment: gracias lo tendre en cuenta si deseo hacer en multiples tablas, lo recomendable seria q fuera valido para sql server y oracle

Comment: sirdiaz, si el caso es que debe funcionar en ambos motores, sugiero que edites tu pregunta para incluir ese dato tan importante, en cuyo caso, tendría que eliminar mi respuesta. Tu pregunta solamente habla de SQL Server.

Comment: estab bien dejala, realmente lo necesito para sql server, gracias